# Android onConfigurationChanged not call in the activity

Tags: android

There is a lot of proposed solution for the problem I am having, but it does not help me to solve my problem, I am a beginner on android here is my function to indicate the layout to display according to the screen orientation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_land);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }
}
```

and this is the config in the Manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".home"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
   android:label=""
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

this the oncreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("Get current Time Zone",Configuration.getCurrentTime());
    Log.e("Get current Time UTC",Configuration.getCurrentTimeUTC());
    StaticObject.setListProdSync(new ArrayList<>());
    //Get the content resolver for your app
    mResolver = getContentResolver();
    // Create the dummy account
    mAccount = CreateSyncAccount(this);

        /**
         *This piece of code will allow us to launch our synchronization every 1mn,
         *  whatever the activity or we are found.
         * by Gaelle
         */
        Handler handlerC = new Handler();
        Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(Configuration.isconnected(context)&& StaticObject.isIsSync() == false){
                    // Add the periodic sync. If the periodic sync is already defined, this will change
                    // the syncing period if it differs.
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
                                .syncPeriodic(SYNC_SECONDS, FLEX_TIME)
                                .setSyncAdapter(mAccount, AUTHORITY)
                                .setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
                        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
                        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, AUTHORITY, true);
                        //synchronization service
                        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                List<SaleInfoSyncEntity> SaleToSync = RoomData.getDB(context).saleInfoSyncDao().getAll();
                                if(!SaleToSync.isEmpty()){
                                    synchronisationData(SaleToSync);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, AUTHORITY, true);
                        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                List<SaleInfoSyncEntity> SaleToSync = RoomData.getDB(context).saleInfoSyncDao().getAll();
                                if(!SaleToSync.isEmpty()){
                                    synchronisationData(SaleToSync);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            handlerC.postDelayed(this,TIME_TO_CHECK);
            }
        };
        handlerC.post(runnableCode);
        /**
         * by Emmanuel Bilong the following statement is to
         * change layout following the orientation of the screen
         */

        if (isLaunched ){
            Toast.makeText(this, "1 st launch " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        findViewById(R.id.modal).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //initialize mode
        StaticObject.setBranchSelected(null);
        StaticObject.setOnlineMode(true);
        StaticObject.setMyCurrency("");
        StaticObject.setBranchNameHome(findViewById(R.id.namBranch));

        //Send profil image
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        ImageView nav_user = hView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfil);

        nav_user.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (StaticObject.getUSER() != null)
                    goToViewProfile(drawer);
        });

        TextView comp = findViewById(R.id.namCompany);
        comp.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (StaticObject.getUserCurrentCompany() == null) {
                    openCreateCompanyView();
                }
        });

        LinearLayout c1 = findViewById(R.id.new_sale_footer);
        c1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewSales.class);
                goToNewView(intent);
        });

        LinearLayout c2 = findViewById(R.id.inventory_footer);
        c2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.feature_not_available);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
        });


        LinearLayout c3 = findViewById(R.id.employee_footer);
        c3.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(home.this, Inventory.class);
                goToNewView(intent);
        });

        LinearLayout c4 = findViewById(R.id.report_footer);
        c4.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(home.this, ListEmployees.class);
                goToNewView(intent);

        });

        LinearLayout listBranches = findViewById(R.id.listBranches);
        listBranches.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (StaticObject.getUserCurrentCompany() != null) {
                    if (StaticObject.getUserCurrentBranch() != null) {
                        openCreateListBranchesView();
                    } else {
                        if (!StaticObject.getUSER().getRoles().get(0).getName()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && !StaticObject
                                .getUSER().getRoles().get(0).getName()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("owner"))
                            return;
                        openCreateBranchView();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    negativePopupCompany("\n" + getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.notification_get_first_company) + "\n", CompanyCreate.class);
                }
            }
        });

         /*
        DEFINE ACTION TO BOTTOM MENU ITEMS
         */
        new MenuConfiguration().addListenerAction(this, R.id.new_sale_footer);
        new MenuConfiguration().addListenerAction(this, R.id.inventory_footer);
        new MenuConfiguration().addListenerAction(this, R.id.employee_footer);
        new MenuConfiguration().addListenerAction(this, R.id.report_footer);


        //for highlight the default selected item in menu. In this case it's home
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            /* use to know if home open from menu (inventory , new sale or Home)
              if from equals to menu, We called Home from menu.*/
        String from = "";
        if (extras != null) {
            from = extras.getString("from");
        }

        if (from.equals("menu")) {
            from = "";
            updateInfo();
        } else {
            if (from.equals(returnCodeForListCompanies + "")) {
                if (StaticObject.isOnlineMode()){
                    getUserCompanies(StaticObject.getUserCurrentCompany());
                }
                else {
                    loadFromDb(StaticObject.getUserCurrentCompany(), null, 2);
                }
            } else {
                if (StaticObject.getUserCurrentBranch() == null) {
                    myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
                            "", getResources().getString(R.string.loginManager_1), true);
                    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("getUserInfo", "getUserInfo");
                            getUserInfo();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    updateInfo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if anyone has an idea, it will be welcome. thank you in advance

Comment: can you share you  full activity class code please.

Comment: the full activity code is under the 30000 lines of code required to submit a post!

Comment: Mai I know Only onCreate method code?

Comment: Yes I just add it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have couple of suggestions

1- Please ensure that you are not calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` anywhere.

2- Use `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` rather than `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thx, it work now, i still have a problem, some disappear in landscape mode!